# Batch Converting PDF to XPS

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I'm looking for an inexpensive way of batch converting 1300 PDF documents to XPS documents.  I know that I can simply print them in that format, but that would take a very long time.  Is there a way to do this programmatically in C#?

Comment: Do you want to convert XPS to PDF or vice versa? Your headline and text don't agree :)

Comment: If you can successfully **print** to XPS, it is only one small step further to also successfully **batch-print** to XPS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your definition of inexpensive there are a couple of options:

**inexpensive = less than $1000:**

You can use PDF2XPS for about $550: http://www.pdftron.com/pdf2xps/index.html

**inexpensive = "free":**

You can follow the suggestions in this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsxps/thread/1917fede-bf5c-4c66-92cd-e97cfa0206cc) to use GhostScript to convert your PDFs to image files, then you can use the [XpsDocumentWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.xpsdocumentwriter.aspx) class to create your documents.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to do it once, then a mixture of custom code and existing solutions could work:

1. Get [FoxIt Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) for free
2. For each document, execute this command:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" -t C:\documents\document1.pdf "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
3. Detect when the "Save the file as" dialog box pops up (Maybe a [Process.GetProcessesByName](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=32) against aplwow64.exe in a Timer?) and use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) to populate the file name and save

   Alternatively, go down the [p/invoke](http://pinvoke.net/) route to call FindWindow and SendMessage directly.