# Server side printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I've been working on a way to submit a print job from my web server.
What I want to do is render an action to pdf then submit the pdf to the default printer on the server.

The code here almost works

```
    public JsonResult Print(String JobName, String TargetAction, String TargetController)
    {
        var job = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue().AddJob(JobName);
        var printStream = job.JobStream;
        try
        {
            var pdfResult = new UrlAsPdf(Url.Action(TargetAction, TargetController, ControllerContext.RouteData));
            var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);


            printStream.Write(binary, 0, binary.Length);
            printStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false, Message = e.Message });
        }
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

But as soon as .Close is called the job is deleted from the printer's queue.  I am using Rotativa to generating the pdf.

It seems right according to the example located here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552913.aspx
But I suspect there is a problem with data being deleted before the printer spooling is done.

Anyone have a suggestion or perhaps a working solution?

Comment: Can you please explain how to print a view.i have a similar scenarion where I need to print my MVC view with default printer and not showing the printer setting window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stream appears to be a PDF, but the spec in your link indicates that you need to be writing device-specific data to `job.JobStream` (EMF or XPS).

To convert to XPS, have a look at this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962156/batch-converting-pdf-to-xps).

Alternatively, [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/23db92d7-1842-408c-aecd-d6036c234230/) suggests that the easiest way to print is via the shell with the "print" verb, e.g.:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("pdfFile.pdf") {Verb = "Print"};
Process.Start(psi);
```

Note that the Acrobat Reader can also [print files from the commandline](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4593625).

Comment: Thanks for the missing bit of knowledge.  I am now using pdftron to print the pdf using their api :)